# Correct way to represent a matrix of vectors.

Tags: matrices, statistics, vectors

Can someone clarify this for me:

Suppose we have two column vectors: **A** = $ \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix} $ and, **B** = $ \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} $.

If **M** consists of **A** & **B** as rows, i.e,  **M** = $ \begin{bmatrix} a&b&c \\ x&y&z \end{bmatrix} $.

Then, is it correct to write  **M** = $ \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{A}^\top\\ \mathbf{B}^\top \end{bmatrix} $?

I have seen people usually write it directly as **M** = $ \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{A} \\ \mathbf{B} \end{bmatrix} $. Here the transpose symbol is omitted. Isn't this incorrect?

We are basically transposing the original vectors when writing them in the matrix, therefore the first representation should be correct.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct in their proper contexts. The majority of the people consider vectors to be columns, some other consider them as rows, and some other see them as both.